# Tabular Array package and stored rows with &

Tags: tables, tabularray

I'm trying to use the tabularray package to generate tables from saved information. My input seems to work with the normal latex tables, but I don't know how the other package reads these inputs. I would much rather use the tblr environment if possible.

```
\newcommand{\savedrow}{cat & dog}

%this code works
\newcommand{\tablex}{%
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        \savedrow
    \end{tabular}
}

%this code doesn't work, it just returns the normal & error
\newcommand{\tblrx}{%
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {c|c}}
        \savedrow
    \end{tblr}
}
```

Appreciate any help you could give, there should be an easy fix to this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: a normal tabular simply expand a command and then continue. tabularray first stores the body unexpanded and then tries to parse that to split it up.  See section 3.2.3 Expand Macros First of the documentation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you so much. This has solved my problem, I just didn't know what it was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\savedrow}{cat & dog}
\begin{tblr}[expand=\savedrow]{colspec={c|c}}
\savedrow
\end{tblr}
\newcommand{\tblrx}{
\begin{tblr}[expand=\savedrow]{colspec={c|c}}
\savedrow
\end{tblr}
}
\tblrx
\end{document}
```

[image]